# Is this safe to unsubscribe DoWork after calling RunWorkerAsync but before the function exits?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I have many methods (they only run one at a time though), they all use the same `RunWorkerCompleated` and `ProgressChanged` methods but they all have different `Dowork` methods. Is it safe to do the following:

```
private void button_Process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgWork_Process.DoWork += Scrub_DoWork;
    bgWork_Process.RunWorkerAsync();
    bgWork_Process.DoWork -= Scrub_DoWork;
}
```

or can I hit a edge case doing this? I did not see anything on the MSDN on it saying it was not allowed and it as (so far) run fine in my program, but I wanted to check here to see if anyone has run in to trouble doing this.

Comment: Yes it is save. and other method is thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do to make sure that the Event Handler isn't being removed until you are done with it would be to do something similar to

```
Action DoWorkAction;

private void button_Process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gbHistory.Enabled = false;
    gbScrub.Enabled = false;
    DoWorkAction = new Action(Scrub_DoWork);
    bgWork_Process.DoWork += DoWorkAction;
    bgWork_Process.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And in whatever handles your completion

```
private void bgWork_Process_CompletedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgWork_Process.DoWork -= DoWorkAction;
}
```

I do feel, however; that it may be better to just have separate `BackGroundWorkers` for all of your Actions that you need to perform instead of sharing a similar one with that or wrap in a class so you can be more clear about what you are doing.

Comment: I think I am going to end up using separate background workers like you suggested, but I still would like to know a definite yes or no on if what I was doing in my OP was safe to do or not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am pretty sure that it is safe since the way that the event pattern works, the event get's fired for the RunWorkerAsync which starts the background worker which already has the delegate for the DoWork Delegate and then you remove it after that has all taken place.

Comment: Thanks, but when and where should I unregister the `RunWorkerCompleted` on a `BackgroundWorker` ?

Comment: You could unregister it in the handler.