# A generic asynchronously assignment

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, lambda

I am trying to create a method which asynchorously assign in a Winforms program using `BackgroundWorker`.

```
void Assign<T>(Func<object> method, ref T obj)
{
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += 
        (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => 
            e.Result = ((Func<object>)(e.Argument))();
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += 
        (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) =>
            obj = (T)e.Result; // Error here
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(method);
}

Assign(slowMethodReturnsFloat, ref aFloatVariable);
Assign(slowMethodReturnsDataSet, ref aDataSetVar);
```

However, I got the error of:

> "Cannot use ref or out parameter inside an lambda expression"

Any other way to implement it? Any approach not using `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return `T`? (nevermind, you're trying to keep the work-flow with BGworker, not make async).

Comment: This `bw.DoWork += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => ...` straight path to memory leak

Comment: @T.S. Can you give some details about the `DoWork` and memory leak?

Comment: You subscribing to event and not unsubscribing. This is one of those things that often let go by programmers. You should do `var handler += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => ...; bw.DoWork += handler;` and then `bw.DoWork -= handler;` See Trap #5 http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/08/31/5-traps-to-avoid-in-csharp.aspx

Comment: @T.S. Thanks. What's the best place to unsubscribe `DoWork` and `RunWorkCompleted`? Inside code piece subscribed by `RunWorkCompleted`? Or Form close? Interesting the MSDN article example even doesn't unsubscribe the events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx.

Comment: If you pass your `bw` to your method than you can do everything outside that method. Yes, you can unsubscribe in the event itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432780/is-this-safe-to-unsubscribe-dowork-after-calling-runworkerasync-but-before-the-f

Comment: @T.S. I added the code for unsubscribing `DoWork` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. However, `RunWorkerCompleted` cannot be unsubscribed itself.

Comment: This is up to your design, of course. but here... `RunWorkerCompleted` has `sender`. You can do `((BackgroundWorker)sender) -= handler;` No?

Comment: @T.S. I've created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315206/unsubscribe-runworkercompleted. It's the "handler" issue.

Comment: Looks like you got all the answers - you need to separate usage and declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider pass an lambda instead of the `ref` as a second argument:

```
void Assign<T>(Func<object> method, Action<T> objSetter)
{
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += 
        (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => 
            e.Result = ((Func<object>)(e.Argument))();
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += 
        (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) =>
            objSetter((T)e.Result);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(method);
}

Assign(slowMethodReturnsFloat, ret => aFloatVariable = ret);
Assign(slowMethodReturnsDataSet, ret => aDataSetVar = ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `T` is but another option might be to pass in a callback:

```
void Assign<T>(Func<object> method, Action<T> callBack);

void callBack(T result)
```