# Unsubscribe RunWorkerCompleted?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following function and I want to unsubscribe `RunWorkerCompleted` when it's done (to prevent memory leak). However I got the error "Use of unassigned local variable 'runWorkerCompleted'"

```
private void Assign<T>(Func<object> method, Action<T> setter)
{
    ShowLoadingLabel();
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    DoWorkEventHandler doWork = (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => e.Result = ((Func<object>)(e.Argument))();
    bw.DoWork += doWork;
    RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler runWorkerCompleted = (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        setter((T)e.Result);
        HideLoadingLabel();
        bw.DoWork -= doWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted -= runWorkerCompleted; // Error
    };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += runWorkerCompleted;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(method);
}
```

How to unsubscribe it?

Comment: There really isn't a compelling reason to do this here.  The entire BGW should just be cleaned up after its work is complete, thus it has no reason to stay alive and hold onto any resources held by its handlers.  Although there *are* situations where this is relevant.  Usually though it's situations where you want the handler to be run only the first time the event is fired

Comment: The function will be used in a subform of an MDI winforms program. I read the subform will not be gced if these events are not unsubscribed. So it will have memory leaks if a user keep open (create new form) and close the form?

Comment: Is the BGW going to outlive the form?  If so, that seems like it'd be problematic if you're displaying the results of the operation to that form.  If the BGW won't outlive the form then you don't have a problem.

Comment: The BGW will be used to get a DataTable and used as data source of a datagridview in the form.

Comment: Which means the form is going to outlive the BGW, so keeping the form alive for as long as the BGW is working isn't a problem, so you have no need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a handler to remove itself you need to follow this general template:

```
DelegateType handler = null;

handler = ()=>
{
    DoOtherStuff();
    someObject.SomeEvent -= handler;
};

someObject.SomeEvent += handler;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign and use in the same line (which it technically still is the initialization line. Just split your line in to two.

```
private void Assign<T>(Func<object> method, Action<T> setter)
{
    ShowLoadingLabel();
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    DoWorkEventHandler doWork = (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => e.Result = ((Func<object>)(e.Argument))();
    bw.DoWork += doWork;
    RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler runWorkerCompleted = null;
    runWorkerCompleted = (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        setter((T)e.Result);
        HideLoadingLabel();
        bw.DoWork -= doWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted -= runWorkerCompleted; // Error
    };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += runWorkerCompleted;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(method);
```

However I think all of this is unessesary as `bw` goes out of scope at the end of the function so there is nothing rooting your delegate so there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is "Used of unassigned local variable" To fix that initialize your `runworkerCompleted` to null and then assign it a value like:

```
RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler runWorkerCompleted = null;
runWorkerCompleted = (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) =>
{
    setter((T)e.Result);
    HideLoadingLabel();
    bw.DoWork -= doWork;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted -= runWorkerCompleted; // Error
};
```